# How can I pass id of multiple row selection to print page at the time of inserting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am inserting data successfully by selecting multiple row table data but at the same time I want to print data on print page.

[image]

In above image I select only 3 record and insert in data base at the time of insert that selected data I want show on my print page.

Create page:

```
  <form>
  <table id="pending_collection_table"> </table>
  <input type="button" id="allocate"  value="allocate" name="allocate"> 
  </form>

<script>
$('#allocate').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

var allVals = [];

$('input[name=selectedBilties]:checked').each(function() {
  allVals.push($(this).val());
});

var formData  = new FormData();
var agent     = $('#agent').val();
var rec_type  = $('#rec_type').val();

formData.append("agent",agent);
formData.append("rec_type",rec_type);

for (var i = 0; i < allVals.length; i++) {
    formData.append('due_ids[]', allVals[i]);
}
 alertify.confirm('Payment Recovery Allocation', 'Do you want to Allocate ?', function(){ 
   $.ajax({
        url :"<?php echo base_url();?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/createPaymentAllocation",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",                
        data:formData,  
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        processData:false,

        success: function(data){
              if(data.PaymentRecAllocation.form_status=='false'){
              }
              else if(data.PaymentRecAllocation.form_status=='true'){
                  alertify.confirm('Payment Recovery Allocation', 'Do you want to print ? ', function(){ 

                 window.location.href =" <?php echo base_url(); ?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/printCollectionRecPage";
                 setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 2000);
             },
                  function(){
                   location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>", 'refresh';
                 });
           }
      } 
   });
}, function(){ 

});
});
</script>
```

Contoller:

```
public function createPaymentAllocation()
  {    
    $bilty_ids     = $this->input->post('due_ids');
    $biltyCount    = count($bilty_ids);
    $agent         = $this->input->post('agent');
    $due_to        = $this->input->post('due_to');

      for($i = 0; $i < $biltyCount; $i++) {
      $data = array(
            'agent_id'            =>$agent,
            'pay_dueto'           =>$due_to,
            'mr_no'               =>$bilty_ids[$i],
             );
      $modelResult = $this->PayRecAllModel->inserPaymentAllocation($data);
    }
      if($modelResult){
         $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
                'form_status'     => 'true',
                'form_message'    => 'Payment Recovery  has been successfully Allocate'
                );
      }else{
            $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
                'form_status'     => 'false',
                'form_message'    => 'Something went wrong.'
            );
      }
      echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Model:

```
public function inserPaymentAllocation($data){
                if($this->db->insert('payment_rec_allocn', $data)){       
                        return  true;
                }else {
                        return  false;
                }
           }
```

And now my print function on `controller`

```
public function printCollectionRecPage(){
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $data= array();
    $data['collnR'] = $this->PayRecAllModel->printCollectionRecPage();
    $this->load->view('crossing/payment_rec_allocation/printCollectionRecovery',$data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
  }
```

model of print page:

```
public function printCollectionRecPage(){
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('payment_rec_allocn');
      $this->db->join('crossing_cash_memo', 'payment_rec_allocn.mr_no = crossing_cash_memo.mr_no');
      $this->db->where('total !=','0');

      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
    }
```

How I can pass ids in print page.

```
 window.location.href =" <?php echo base_url(); ?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/printCollectionRecPage";
```

How can I pass that selected ids on print page.
And my print page I have table to show data of selected data on inset time.

Comment: What happens to 4 & 5?

Comment: @Strawberry after insert 3 record next time I will insert 4 & 5

Comment: So, do 4 & 5 get stored somewhere in the interim, or are they generated afresh each time?

Comment: @Strawberry 4 & 5 is not the issue I can select all records but it shows me  all previous data stored in my data base. I just want to show selected record show on my print page.

Comment: So you insert 5 records, but, at the same time, only want to pass 3 of them to the next page?

Comment: @Strawberry no it insert only selected record 1 record or all record at a time.

Comment: So you *want to* insert 5 records, *and*, at the same time, want to pass just the 3 selected to the next page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert_id()` function

```
public function inserPaymentAllocation($data){
    if($this->db->insert('payment_rec_allocn', $data)){
                $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                return  $insert_id;
    }else {
            return  false;
    }
}
```

store returned ids into array

```
$modelResult[] = $this->PayRecAllModel->inserPaymentAllocation($data);

if(!empty($modelResult)){
     $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
            'form_status'     => 'true',
            'form_message'    => 'Payment Recovery  has been successfully Allocate',
            'form_ids'    => $modelResult
            );
 }
```

Pass the ids to your controller for print

```
var ids = data.PaymentRecAllocation.form_ids.join(',');

window.location.href =" <?php echo base_url(); ?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/printCollectionRecPage?ids="+ids;
```

But in case of multiple inserts you should ideally use

```
$this->db->trans_start();
//all your insertion code here
//if anything breaks the db will be rollback
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined` this error

Comment: This answer gives basic overview to give you idea. I have not tested it. Do you get the ids in `$modelResult` array?

Comment: @sheryas its return only 1 id